# If error, skip to next in Powershell (Microsoft Teams)

Tags: powershell, if-statement, error-handling

Good evening,

I have written a piece of code in Powershell that takes a .csv file as input, and create a new
Microsoft Team with the channels and users in the .csv

The script is working, but i dont really like the part where i add the owners to the team. I recieve a list of ID's in the .csv file, but i can only add the owners with a mailadres. This would be a easy loop, but there are 3 possible domains that the user is connected to.

My goal is to have a piece of code that adds @domain1.nl to the ID that i get in the .csv, and try to add the user. if i receive a error because that address does not exist, it will try to add the owner with @domain2.nl and @domain3.nl added to it. If nothing works, it should give a Write-Host that says "This domain has to be added"

Below is the piece of code that works, but i think its not the best way to it and it could be improved.

```
    #Adding the owners to the Team
    if ($d.ID) {
        $Error.Clear()
        try {
            $ID = $d.ID + "@domain1.nl"
            Add-TeamUser -GroupId $GroupID -User $ID -Role Owner
        } catch { "Error occured" }
        if ($Error) {
            $Error.Clear()
            try {
                $ID = $d.ID + "@domain2.nl"
                Add-TeamUser -GroupId $GroupID -User $ID -Role Owner
            } catch { "Error occured" }
            if ($Error) {
                $Error.Clear()
                try {
                $ID = $d.ID + "@domain3.nl"
                Add-TeamUser -GroupId $GroupID -User $ID -Role Owner
                } catch { "Error occured" }
                if ($Error) {
                  Write-Host "This domain has to be added to the code"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `try` / `catch` inside a `foreach` loop:

```
$ok = $false
foreach ($domain in '@domain1.nl', '@domain2.nl', '@domain3.nl') {
  try {
    Add-TeamUser -GroupId $GroupID -User ($d.ID + $domain) -Role Owner
    $ok = $true
  } catch {
    Write-Warning "Error occurred with domain $domain."
  }
  if ($ok) { break }
}

if (-not $ok) { 
  Write-Error 'This domain has to be added to the code'
}
```

Comment: Yes that worked great! Thank you, learned something new again!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, @pro10boi96; my pleasure.